# PHP string can contains only English & numbers and '-'

Tags: php, string, preg-match

I am trying to do that my string can only contains  English & numbers and '**-**'

I tried this :

```
elseif (!preg_match('/[A-Za-z].*[0-9]|[0-9].*[A-Za-z]/', $link)){echo 'error';} // Always returning error..
```

But its not working .

Example string can be :

**jhondo**

**jhon-do**

**jhon-do9**

Comment: Try `preg_match('~^[A-Z0-9-]*$~iD', $link)`. What are exact requirements? How many `-` can there be? Can the hyphen appear at the start/end of the string?

Comment: or `([\w\d-]+)`

Comment: @JustCarty `[\w\d-]+` is equal to `[\w-]+` and if no `u` modifier is provided, it is equal to `[a-zA-Z0-9_-]+`, i.e. it also matches `_`. And without anchors, it will match even those strings that contain chars other than English letters, digits or `-`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew  unlimited - can be because each space replaced by - .

Comment: @JustCarty `\w` matches word chars, that is letters, digits, `_` (and if you specify `u` modifier, even some more).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks its worked, make it as answer and i will put a V

Comment: @DaniPrime I added an answer with explanations and pattern variations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may use

```
preg_match('~^[A-Z0-9-]*$~iD', $link)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GRBVrH/2).

**Pattern details**

- `^` - start of string
- `[A-Z0-9-]*` - 0 or more (replace `*` with `+` to match 1 or more) ASCII letters, digits or `-` (note that `i` modifier makes the pattern case insensitive and `-` at the end of the character class does not have to be escaped)
- `$` - the very end of string since `D` modifier makes it match only at the very end of the string.

If the `-` char can only appear in between letters/digits and cannot appear at start/end of the string, use `'~^[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*$~iD'` (to match a non-empty string) or `'~^(?:[A-Z0-9]+(?:-[A-Z0-9]+)*)?$~iD'` (to also match an empty string).

If you just want to avoid matching a string with two consecutive `-` chars, add a `(?!.*--)` negative lookahead at the start: `'~^(?!.*--)[A-Z0-9-]*$~iD'`.